# Bootstrap img-responsive not working?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am just learning front end development. I would like you to tell me why img-responsive is not working. Here is the my code. And yeah If I am doing couple of other bad practises do tell me.

HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="background">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12">
    <h1 class="text-center heading">H.G Wells</h1>
  <hr>  
     </div> 
        </div>
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6"> 
     <div id="word1">
       <h2 class="text-center">Father of Science friction books</h2>
       <div class="img-responsive img-rounded">
       <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e8/Grateful_Dead_-_Jerry_Garcia.jpg" alt="HGWells" >
     </div>
     </div>
    </div>  
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body{
  top-margin:60px;
}
.heading{
  font-size:400%;
}
.background{
  background-color:lightgrey;
  margin-top:5rem;
}
#word1{
  margin-top:1rem;
  margin-bottom:1rem;
  color:black;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which version of Bootstrap are you using? If you are using version 4, they changed it to `img-fluid`:

```
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e8/Grateful_Dead_-_Jerry_Garcia.jpg" alt="HGWells" class="img-fluid img-rounded">
```

Comment: thank you. It worked I did not look at my version. just using pencode of freecodecamp.

Comment: but may I ask img-responsive is working on my friend pencode even though he uses twitter-bootstrap 4

Comment: Not sure why that would be. Seems pretty strange. Maybe some other setting in the pencode is different.

Answer (score 2):

The classes `img-responsive img-rounded` go on the [img](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#images) element, not the div

Ex:

```
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e8/Grateful_Dead_-_Jerry_Garcia.jpg" alt="HGWells"  lass="img-responsive img-rounded">`
```